# Can't connect to MongoDB Atlas with MONGO_URL environmental variable

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-connection, connection-string

I am trying to connect to my MongoDB cluster from the terminal when starting my Meteor app with the below command:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb+srv://<myUserName>:<myPassword>@XXXXXX-tdumu.mongodb.net/meteor?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
MAIL_URL="smtp://smtp@XXXXXX.com.tr:<myPassword>;@mail.xxxxx.com.tr:587"
meteor --settings settings-dev.json
```

It worked perfectly from the beginning, but now I'm getting the below error.

> Error: queryTxt ENOTIMP xxxxxx-tdumu.mongodb.net at
>   QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:213:19) 
>   => Exited with code: 1
>   => Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

This problem started when I'm connected to a Wi-Fi network other than my home. I already whitelisted `0.0.0.0/0` on MongoDB Atlas. But it crashes randomly. Yesterday it was working without any hiccups, today I could'nt get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I went and removed IP whitelist and added 0.0.0.0/0 again. Seems to solve this issue, but I get this error randomly.I don't know what goes on at the MongoDB Atlas backend.

Comment: One of my colleagues gets the same error from his home connection. It might be an issue about the ISP I don't know. When I am connected to home router I get this error. When I am connected to my mobile phone hotspot there are no errors. The issue is temporarily solved by resetting IP whitelist.